# How do i check creation time of a ES doc in ES 7.3v?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know the creation time of my document in elasticsearch, is there any meta field which keeps this information or if it's not there then how do i implement it.

I am making upsert request everytime and so providing time is not possible.

upsert request is:

```
POST test/_update/document_id
{
"doc": {
 "field1": "value1",
 "field2": "value2",
 "field3": "value3",
 "relationship": {
  "parent": "child"
 }
},
 "doc_as_upsert": "true"
}
```

using elasticsearch npm and the following code:

```
esDoc.doc['relationship'] = { name: "test" };
esDoc['doc_as_upsert'] = true;
bulkQueue.add({ update: { _index: ES_INDEX_PREFIX + testId, _id: _id } }, esDoc)
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to achieve this is to leverage [ingest pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) and record the value of [`_ingest.timestamp`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/accessing-data-in-pipelines.html#accessing-ingest-metadata) in the document.

First create the following ingest pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/set_timestamp
{
  "description": "adds the timestamp when a document is indexed",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "indexed_at",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when indexing new documents, simply reference that pipeline in your request:

```
PUT tmp/_doc/1?pipeline=set_timestamp
{
  "test": "foo"
}
```

And your document will contain a new field called `indexed_at` containing the exact timestamp at which it was indexed:

```
GET tmp/_doc/1
{
  "test" : "foo",
  "indexed_at" : "2019-10-03T13:19:03.181Z"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you're using the Update API with document upsert, you don't have access to the ingest pipelines. What I suggest doing is a [`scripted_upsert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#scripted_upsert) instead, like this:

```
POST test/_update/document_id
{
 "scripted_upsert":true,
 "script": {
   "source": """
     // update all fields
     ctx._source.putAll(params); 

     // add timestamp the first time
     if (ctx._source.indexed_at == null) {
        def now = Instant.ofEpochMilli(new Date().getTime());
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, ZoneId.of('Z'));
        ctx._source.indexed_at = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
     }
   """,
   "params": {
     "field1": "value1",
     "field2": "value2",
     "field3": "value3",
     "relationship": {
       "parent": "child"
     }
   }
 },
 "upsert": {}
}
```

Comment: not working with "doc" type partial update POST request.

Comment: can u suggest me a way which could work with partial update request as well as this method only works for simple indexing of doc and not with update.

Comment: You mentioned "creation time", so that must mean indexing and not updating, right?

Comment: you are right sir but all my indexing request are of type upsert only that's why i am not able to use this way.

Comment: Which client are you using? Can you show one of your upsert queries?

Comment: sure sir, i am using elasticsearch npm and i have updated my request in the question above.

Comment: Update your question please, it's not legible in comments.

Comment: Since you're using javascript, why not simply adding a new field `esDoc.doc['indexed_at'] = new Date().toISOString();` to your document?

Comment: but if this same doc gets updated then the indexed_at field will also get changed sir.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is described [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17895) indeed.

Comment: What's the reason for upserting instead of simply indexing since the doc is always the same whether indexing or updating?

Comment: but i am changing the contents of the doc every time i make a upsert request i.e i partially update the contents of the doc hence the doc content's are not same in each request.