# Elasticsearch adding timestamp to every doc - Created at and updated at

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I automatically add timestamps for every document

 I want two timestamps

- "created_at": when document is indexed
- "updated_at": when a docuemnt is modified

I believe I should be using pipeline, but I dont know how to differntiate between Insert & Update operations

Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer might help for indexing time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219945/how-do-i-check-creation-time-of-a-es-doc-in-es-7-3v/58220054#58220054

Comment: For update time, you need to explain how you're updating documents. What is your process?

Comment: @Val I am using bulk API with _update using doc_id as reference

Comment: Then why your client code would not be able to add that update date in the document?

Comment: it can but i would not prefer...since we have multiple client code bases and any can update elasticsesrch.......i would prefer if this modified date is embeded into pipeline

Comment: The only problem is that the update operations [cannot leverage ingest pipelines](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17895)

Comment: other than pipeline is there any equivalent of mysql Auto_update: last modified date?

Comment: I can see a way to do it, but can you show a typical update (json + code) that you're sending?